# How to display field values as hyperlink based on a condition in access forms?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have an access form in which a particular values of a particular field needs to be displayed as hyperlink if it is greater than 0. If the value is lesser than or equal to zero it should not be displayed as a hyperlink. How do I specify this condition in access?

Answer (score 0):

A hyperlink is a Label field.
So change the Label.caption, label.forecolor and label.hyperlinkaddress
values depending on the value.

Comment: Sorry, can you please help me get a better idea? The values for this particular field come from a table. Where exactly would I write the condition? For eg. if there are 100 records how would I iterate through the values and find what needs to be displayed as hyperlink and what not to be?